# How to change display name in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build a firebase cloud function to change a display name.

I know that i can do it easily in android, but since every time i change the display name i need to update all user records and since there isn't seem to be a way to get notified in firebase function when display name has changed (please correct me if i am wrong), i am planning to make the change in firebase and on the same time make the records update.

This is how i started...

```
exports.changeDisplayName = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
console.log(`User ${context.auth.uid} has requested to change its display name`);

//If user not authenitacted, throw an error
if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token && (context.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider === 'phone'))) {
    
    if (!context.auth) {
        console.log(`User ${context.auth.uid} without auth`);
    }

    if (!context.auth.token) {
        console.log(`User ${context.auth.uid} without token`);
    }

    if (!context.auth.token.phoneNumber) {
        console.log(`User ${context.auth.uid} without phone number (${context.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider})`);
    }

    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'permission-denied',
        'Must be an authenticated user with cellphone to change display name'
      );
}

// Change display display name from data

// update firebase contacts

});
```

Comment: What's your question? It sounds like you just need to finish implementing your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update a user's name from Cloud Functions, you'll be using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js users. Through that, you can [update any properties of a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) with something like this:

> ```
> admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
>   email: 'modifiedUser@example.com',
>   phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
>   emailVerified: true,
>   password: 'newPassword',
>   displayName: 'Jane Doe',
>   photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
>   disabled: true
> })
>   .then(function(userRecord) {
>     // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
>     console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
>   })
>   .catch(function(error) {
>     console.log('Error updating user:', error);
>   });
> ```

Comment: function passes without any warning or errors but when i am reading FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() in android, does not change, does it make sense? Do i need to refresh local auth or something?

Comment: found it. FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reload();